# MaxOpenFiles based on Indexes X Shards X Replicas X Documents

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

### Problem

Currently I have an elasticsearch cluster that is **running out of file descriptors**, and checking elasticsearch setup documentation page I saw that is **recommended to set the number of file descriptors on the machine to 32K or even 64K** and digging a bit on search results I found **some people** that set this limit to a **threshold even higher (128K or unlimited)**.

The exception I'm getting is quite common to the exhaustion of file descriptors:

```
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockReleaseFailedException: Cannot forcefully unlock a NativeFSLock which is held by another indexer component
```

### Question

Is there an equation for the number of file descriptors we should expect to be required by elasticsearch / lucene based on the number of Indexes, Shards, Replicas and / or Documents? Or even foor the number of files for all elasticsearch indexes?

I wouldn't like to set it by try and error, and unlimited number of file descriptors isn't possible for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

I know very little about elasticsearch but will try to answer this from Lucene perspective.

I'm afraid there's no easy way of finding out how many descriptors do you really need.

First, this depends on [`Directory`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html?is-external=true) implementation (which itself depends on the underlying OS, if you use `FSDirectory.open(File)`).

Secondly, it also depends on your merge policy (which may depend on Lucene version, unless elasticsearch overrides it).

Finally, it can even depend on various exotic circumstances, such as garbage collection behaviour (if certain bits depend on finalizers to free resources). We even had an instance of Lucene which was leaking file descriptors until we manually switched `-d64` mode on.

Above said, I would recommend you to set up a monitoring script which gathers some stats over a week or so and come up with the range fitting your typical usage. Add some variance for unexpected cases.

P.S. I am struggling to imagine a case these days where file descriptors would be a genuine problem. Is this a [C10K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) problem? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: +1 good explanation. The complexity with elasticsearch is just that you have multiple indices with potentially multiple shards each, where each shard is a lucene instance. Also, sockets are listed as open file descriptors too. Do note though that a high number of shards is required mainly during segments merging, thus you'll see spikes there, elasticsearch doesn't use that many file descriptors all the time. You can easily monitor open file descriptors through [node stats api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html).